# mysql query with serialize data

Tags: php, mysql

Here I attached screenshot of my phpmyadmin serialized data(marked).
Now I want to retrieve Raisul Where booked is 1_5.

Can you please help me to write simple mysql query?

[image]

Comment: Storing serialized data in a table is crazy if you need to match against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from tablename where booked like '%"1_5"%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE booked REGEXP '.*s:[0-9]+:".1_5.".*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '.*s:[0-9]+:".1_5.".*'
```